# How to delete last row if I have a `auto increment` field also

Tags: php

I want to delete the last row of table.

**Query:**

```
delete from NEXG.user_type where `id`=last_insert_id()
```

`id` is auto increment key.

But it is showing **0 rows affected**.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: last_insert_id() is only valid in the same request.... if you haven't inserted any new rows in this request, then you can't use last_insert_id(), and will have to rely on `MAX(id)` instead.... if this is a multi-user system, then that's very dangerous practise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SIMPLY:

```
DELETE FROM `user_type` 
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yeah! It worked . I think we can't use `from` clause and `where` clause together to delete a row. @chayan

Comment: Obviously you can.  [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).